# How to manually select elements from a list encoded in utf-8?

Tags: python, list, utf-8, devanagari

I have a list which looks like this:

> ['क', ',', 'म', '-', 'ह', 'औ', "'", ')', '(', 'स', '.', 'ए', 'प', 'श',
>   'भ', 'ल', 'य', 'न', 'इ', '}', 'ज', 'र', 'उ', 'ग', 'द', 'त', 't', 'थ',
>   'ब', 'अ', 'ई', 'o', '%', 'व', 'a', 'आ', '#', '–', 'q', 'i', '।', '/',
>   'ओ', 'फ', 'f', 's', 'u', '!', '?', 'ध', 'ऐ', '१', '+', '२', 'p', 'd',
>   'j', 'च', 'ऑ', 'b', 'छ', 'ऊ', 'l', 'e', 'w', 'ख', 'घ', 'c', 'r', 'y',
>   'g', 'n', 'ट', 'ड', 'x', '५', '"', '३', 'm', 'ठ', 'h', '४', '•', '$',
>   '>', 'v', 'z', 'झ', '७', '—', '६', 'k', 'ढ', '८', '&', 'ऋ', '\', '९',
>   '✉', '०', '॥', '°', '^', '~', '−', '·', 'ॐ', '×', '_', '→', '☆', '£',
>   '€', 'α', '‘', 'ष', '±', '†', 'β', '@', '\u200e', '░', '¬', '₹', 'π',
>   '½', '…', 'ऍ', 'º', 'σ', 'γ', 'δ', 'ऽ', '0', '²', 'ङ', 'ॠ', 'à', '≥',
>   'ः', 'ऎ', 'ω', 'μ', '{', 'ण', 'ं', '≈', 'ε', 'λ', 'θ', '्', '<', '↑',
>   '\uf0a7', 'φ', '\u200b', '', 'ञ', 'о', 'ƒ', '©', '←', 'ळ', 'ा', '■',
>   '¢', 'ρ', '∞', 'î', '⁄', '√', 'ব', '§', '¾', '≤', '॰', '্', 'é', 'و',
>   '`', '¥', '♂', '₩', 'å', '´', 'ü', 'á', 'ó', 'ভ', 'в', '¼', '़', 'è',
>   'ʁ', 'े', 'и', '≡', 'ζ', 'í', '↙', '″', '\u200d', '₫', 'م', '»', 'ː',
>   '‡', 'ö', 'ँ', 'د', 'η', 'ð', '♦', 'শ', 'প', 'ी', 'ú', '⅓', 'ب', '≠',
>   'κ', '∈', 'ç', '�', 'এ', 'উ', 'র', 'ν', 'â', 'ê', 'ū', 'к', 'ø', 'ù',
>   'ā', 'ä', 'æ', '↓', 'ô', 'স', 'ो', 'ō', '●', 'ē', '₨', 'ि', '„', 'ī',
>   '฿', 'ò', 'τ', 'ਸ', 'ऩ', 'ª', 'р', 'ত', 'н', 'с', 'χ', 'ಕ', 'ë', 'ॉ',
>   'خ', 'ا', 'ψ', 'а', '¿', 'ì', 'ý', 'µ', 'ौ', 'š', '‰', '÷', 'ি', 'আ',
>   'ə', 'у', '★', 'ل', 'ॡ', 'č', '⊕', 'ृ', 'ñ', 'ै', 'û', 'ु', 'ू', 'м',
>   'þ', 'г', 'ι', 'മ', 'پ', '☉', 'த', 'ш', '¤', 'е', '', 'ş', 'ã', 'ž',
>   'খ', 'ع', '水', 'õ', 'ক', 'д', 'ï', 'ج', 'ধ', 'ж', 'ऒ', 'ଓ', '¹', 'ॅ',
>   'ħ', 'ন', 'ও', 'ʃ', '\u200c', 'ز', 'х', 'מ', '⊂', 'ф', 'য', 'എ',
>   '\u202a', 'ষ', '九', '♣', 'ł', 'ऌ', 'া', 'త', 'з', 'ß', 'ف', 'ר', '―',
>   'п', 'غ', 'ऱ', 'ر', 'ŋ', 'ϕ', 'ऴ', 'ክ', 'ğ', 'ą', 'ś', 'ę', '¨', 'ч',
>   'ż', '№', 'س', 'œ', 'ă', '♠', 'ش', '◾', '\uf0fc', 'ÿ', 'ש', '\ufeff',
>   'ಜ', 'ن', 'ʊ', '³', 'ć', 'آ', 'চ', 'ɛ', 'я', '이', 'đ', 'জ', 'ġ', '⅜',
>   'ɑ', '˚', 'ξ', 'л', 'б', 'т', 'ц', '∟', 'й', 'ಭ', 'സ', 'ɒ', 'అ', 'న',
>   '⍨', '⌛', '⌣', 'ĝ', 'ő', 'ĉ', '،', 'ċ', 'ĵ', 'ژ', 'হ', 'ŝ', 'ণ', '沖',
>   '⅞', 'ت', '١', 'ɸ', 'ɪ', 'ʌ', 'ě', 'ע', '¸', 'দ', 'ŭ', '∧', 'أ', 'અ',
>   'ɨ', 'ĥ', '∀', 'ગ', 'ű', 'ʒ', 'ح', 'ث', '█', '∩', 'ق', '↔', '®', 'ਪ',
>   '⇒', '⅔', '∑', '⇔', 'ழ', 'ю', '月', 'ذ', 'ǻ', 'ń', '∪', 'ك', 'ʰ', 'ё',
>   'э', '™', 'ض', 'ਦ', 'ɹ', '☞', 'ঞ', 'ম', 'ু', '②', '道', 'ӏ', '大', 'щ',
>   'א', 'ʔ', 'ǁ', 'ה', '∂', 'ţ', 'പ', '∨', '성', 'ỳ', 'ബ', '∇', 'ظ', 'ط',
>   'ẽ', 'ص', 'ಶ', 'υ', 'ഞ', 'қ', 'ỹ', 'ź']

I need to select only the Devanagari characters (i.e. `'अ', 'आ'`...`'क','ख','घ'`..) out of above characters. Is there any other way to do this in python except that of manually selecting the indices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through each item in the list, convert each character to a unicode number using `ord`, then test whether it lies within the Devanagari unicode character range (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari_(Unicode_block)). If it does, add it to the output list.

It will end up something like this:

```
newlist = []
for c in list:
    if ord(c) >= 2304 and ord(c) <= 2431:
        newlist.append(c)
```

Comment: Or simply  `2304 <= ord(c) <= 2431`. Note that there's also [Devanagari Extended](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/UA8E0.pdf) that OP may want to check as well.